# JPA Repository Query Language - AND with OR not working properly

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I am working on a project that has a JPA Repository with queries. One of the queries has an `And` and `Or` at the same query but it does not work properly.

```
List<Partner> findDistinctByUserNameNotNullAndPartnerNoInAndUserNameLikeOrFirstNameLikeOrderByPartnerNo(
        List<Integer> partnerNos, String userName, String firstName);
```

What happens is that when I pass `no Filter` it returns around `65 rows`, when I pass a `Filter` for example "MAR" it returns `265 rows` which does not make sense since the query with no filters is fetching all rows. What I have observed is that at the `UserNameLikeOrFirstNameLike` the `Or` is dividing the Query. He is looking for a `Partner` inside the list with the `UserName Like` `OR he just looks for a FirstName like something else.`

I know what is the problem but I don't know how to solve it.

Making it short: How can I put an `And` and an `Or` at the same JPA Query and make it work properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a want to achieve it using named repository method it will be like :

```
findDistinctByUserNameNotNullAndPartnerNoInAndUserNameLikeOrPartnerNoInAndFirstNameLikeOrderByPartnerNo(List<Integer> partnerNos, String userName, String firstName);
```

but it is always  recommended to use  short and readable method names , for which you can use [JPA NamedQueries](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.named-queries) or [@Query](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query)